# WPF and Awesomium control behind tab not resizing

Tags: wpf, awesomium

I have in a WPF application a TabControl. In one of its tabs, I have a WebControl class (from Awesomium.Net).

When I resize the window with this tab as active, the browser is resized.

When I resize the window with another tab as active, the browser is not resized. When I came back to the tab with the browser control, the control is still at the old size.

How can I workaround this?

I've tried to hack the TabControl.SelectionChanged event, but with no success :

My xaml :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.awesomium.com/winfx"      
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525"       >
    <Grid>    
        <TabControl
            SelectionChanged="Tabs_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem
                Header="MyTab" Name="MyTab" >
                <Grid>
                    <Custom:WebControl x:Name="browser" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Another tab">
                <Grid>                       
                </Grid>
            </TabItem> 
        </TabControl>
      </Grid>
</Window>
```

and my code behind:

```
private void Tabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tabs = e.Source as TabControl;
    if (tabs != null && tabs.SelectedItem == myTab)
    {
        var parent = browser.Parent as FrameworkElement;
        parent.UpdateLayout();

        // also tried
        parent.InvalidateArrange();
        // also tried
        browser.InvalidateArrange();
        // also tried
        parent.Width -= 1;
        parent.InvalidateArrange();
        parent.Width += 1;

    }
}
```

**[Edit]** When I attach the application with WPFInspector, I can see that the WebControl itself is actually resized. It seems that it's the internal control (which one), that is not resized properly.

**[Edit 2]** Another, unsucesfull test:

```
    private static readonly System.Reflection.PropertyInfo g_WebControlIsDirtyProperty = typeof(WebControl).GetProperty("IsDirty");
    private void Tabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabs = e.Source as TabControl;
        if (tabs != null && tabs.SelectedItem == myTab)
        {
            g_WebControlIsDirtyProperty.SetValue(
                browser,
                true
                );
        }
    }
```

**[Edit 3]** I've played a bit with [AvalonDock 2.0](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/). The bahavior is identical.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the visual tree with Snoop to double check the grid containing the browser received the resize properly as well?

Comment: I've edited my question. I used another tools, but the conclusion is the WPF side is correct.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but you could bind the Width/Height of the control to the Grid's ActualWidth/ActualHeight.

Comment: Did you mean I should do this: `<Grid>
                    <Custom:WebControl
                        x:Name="browser"
                        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
                        Height="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                </Grid>`? I change that, but there is no change in the behavior. As I said, the WebControl itself is correctly sized. But the inner control, out of my control, is not.

Comment: [Link to the bug report on the vendor site](http://support.awesomium.com/discussions/problems/956-wpf-webcontrol-resize).

Comment: @user7116 that is a broken link

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same issue, when I initially loaded up the WebControl I couldn't get the actual content of the website to show until I re-sized the WebControl manually. I did manage to find a workaround though inspired by your invalidate calls.
 I called browser.Invalidate**Measure**() after my initial loading. For your case I suspect you need to put it in the selection changed of the TabControl.